# Adding dynamic value to href javascript using createElement

Tags: javascript, dynamic, label, href, createelement

```
var newCell = row.insertCell(4);
var element5 = document.createElement("label");
element5.innerHTML = "<td><a data-toggle='modal' href='javascript:deleteRow('" + thisAddrNames[i] + "');' ></a></td>";
newCell.appendChild(element5);
```

My Question is I am trying to add `thisAddrNames` dynamically in javascript. I fetch the value from a php and am trying to pass it to `deleteRow` function. However, I am unable to do so. Please help.

Comment: Coz it s a column in a row in a table..

Comment: the cell s already thr.. v shudn create it again?

Comment: I could tackle my problem in a different approach without using the dynamic value fetching. Thanks all for the support.